# How do I store my state in localstorage in my Redux application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to build a Trello clone using React and Redux.

Details of the application:

- The application consists of 4 columns called TODO, DOING, DONE and REJECTED
- I can add card to any of the 4 columns.
- In the card I have just plain text.
- The cards can be further moved into any of the columns using a package called react-beautiful-dnd.
- There is also a delete button sticked to each card to delete the card which is added.

What I am trying to do?

- I have a sample data which is first rendered when the application is first loaded.
- The data is just demo, and contains id, text property for each and every card.
- I want to use localstorage to add the card and further delete the card.
- I want to use possibly Redux subscribe to achieve this.

**I do not have much experience in dealing with Redux and localstorage altogether.
How can I do this?
Any help would be really appreciated and much required.**

I have my codesandbox where I have my application running. Please consider checking out to help me out.
https://codesandbox.io/s/small-violet-zmbtf

Comment: Why are you using localstorage. Why arent you using redux store to hold the data and share it in your app. You can than hydrate and re-hydrate the store in local storage so that you dont loose the store on page refresh

Comment: Have you seen this library yet? https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist

Comment: I want my data to be persistent, so that it wont get lost after the refresh

Comment: @johnmikelridzz Not really, how should I be using it

Comment: I would recommend using `React`'s built in contexts (https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) instead of `Redux`.  Redux bloats apps and is generally unnecessary in 2020.

Comment: I have already built it with Redux, replacing everything is expensive. I am looking for just localstorage integration

Comment: just read the docs of how to add it, it's fairly easy. What it will do is make a key, value pair of a key that you will give it (it's in the setup) and a value of a string version of your current redux state. 

But I am curious though why you would want to do this? Can it not be solved by remotely fetching the state everytime you need the data?

Comment: would you mind contributing to my code? I have put my codesandbox link. It would be really helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [redux persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist)

```
// configureStore.js

import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage' // defaults to localStorage for web

import rootReducer from './reducers'

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)

export default () => {
  let store = createStore(persistedReducer)
  let persistor = persistStore(store)
  return { store, persistor }
}
```

```
// App.js

import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react'

// ... normal setup, create store and persistor, import components etc.

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <RootComponent />
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

**Edited check below:**
change codesandbox to:

store/index.js:

```
// store/index.js:
import { createStore } from "redux";
import { persistStore } from "redux-persist";
import rootReducer from "../reducers";

export const store = createStore(rootReducer);

export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

*******
    reducers/index.js:

```
// reducers/index.js:
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import { persistReducer } from "redux-persist";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
import listReducers from "./listReducers";

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage,
  whitelist: ["lists"]
};

export default persistReducer(persistConfig, combineReducers({
  lists: listReducers
}));
```

root project index.js:

```
// index.js:
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";
import { store, persistor } from "./store";
import "./styles/main.scss";

import App from "./components/App";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
      <App />
    </PersistGate>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Comment: Sorry, it does not work, Persistgate induces error. would you mind contributing to my codesandbox, please? Here is the link https://codesandbox.io/s/small-violet-zmbtf